# Not able to load static files in Django

Tags: django-staticfiles

I am very new to Django. As per my lessons, I have tried developing a django proejct/. However, I am not able to load static files or the css views. I have attached screenshots of my project and Django codes.
Request you all to please view and help. Looking forward. [image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWDNZ.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to read the code rendered in the browser via Develepor tools and then check if static files are being loaded or not, if yes then check the relative path in your html and if not then follow the right convention of storing and configuring settings for static files in django

Edit this in your settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

And also move around this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = ["F:/..../site/public/static"]  #1

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/..../site/public/static' #2
     
    #Any one of these these #1 and #2 would work 
    
STATIC_URL = '/static/' # and set this as root for each web-app or general convention of placing static files
```

Also check `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` in your installed apps in settings.py

Comment: did that but result still remains the same only.

Comment: I have edited above answer please check and if it still doesn't help then post screenshots of rendered code in browser